# Assets pipeline in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I tried to find the importance of assets pipeline in net but could not get any clarity on it. Why are few gems placed in group :assets and mentioned not required in production in comments part ? I have three small questions to get clarified.

What do we exactly mean by assets PIPELINE ?
Why do we need assets group ?
Why don't we need these gems in production ?

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Essential reading here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

> ## What is the Asset Pipeline?
>
> The asset pipeline provides a framework
>   to concatenate and minify or compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It
>   also adds the ability to write these assets in other languages such as
>   CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

The reason for separating these particular gems into their own group, is that they are not needed in production, when `rake assets:precompile` is run, it creates all of the assets in a form that web browsers can understand *(these are stored in the public directory once you've deployed)*

e.g. CoffeeScript is compiled into javascript, sass is compiled into CSS. Uglifier just minifies the javascript.

Comment: so when we move to production , with help of `rake assets:precompile` command, all these assets are stored in PUBLIC folder such that these gems are no longer required. Is my understanding right ?

Comment: The gems are required for the compilation to take place, but their code does not need to be loaded in the production application